# Como obter valores de uma coluna de várias tabelas apresentadas em uma página web?

Tags: html

Numa página da Web, há uma ou mais tabelas com informações das quais preciso obter em forma de lista.

Especificamente, preciso obter uma lista dos valores da 2ª coluna de uma tabela da página Web que eu informar. Como por exemplo, as páginas abaixo.

[image: Parte da publicação do Diário Oficial de MT de 17/12/2013]
Link: https://www.iomat.mt.gov.br/do/navegadorhtml/mostrar.htm?id=630236&edi_id=3580

[image: Parte da publicação do Diário Oficial de MT de 17/12/2013]
Link: https://www.iomat.mt.gov.br/do/navegadorhtml/mostrar.htm?id=630237&edi_id=3580

Atualmente, eu copio a tabela para uma planilha e depois filtro a lista.
Mas se tivesse um script (Python, Ruby ou Perl) ou programa (Java ou C#) que apenas informasse o link e ele já retornasse a lista seria uma mão na roda.

A página com este tipo de matéria tem sempre um dos padrões acima.

Comment: Qual linguagem afinal? Para cada linguagem que você citou haverão diferentes ferramentas de *web crawling*.

Comment: Você tentou fazer esse script? Qual a problema aconteceu enquanto você tentava? Qual o código que deu problema? Qual é a pergunta exatamente?

Comment: Como eu especifiquei na pergunta, qualquer script ou programa. Quem já tiver alguma solução parecida baseada nesta dúvida.

Comment: Abra o console do Chrome (`Ferramentas > Console Javascript`) e escreva `$x("//tr[position() > 1]/td[2]/p/span/text()")`.

Comment: Exatamente @rodrigorgs. Poderia postar como resposta. Obrigado pelo seu tempo.

Comment: Não posso postar como resposta enquanto a questão está *em suspenso*.

Comment: Como eu poderia reformular a pergunta para que fosse aprovada? Não vejo como ficar mais claro o que estou precisando. Eu postei na pergunta a solução que eu utilizo (mesmo que tosca, eu sei), mas queria algo mais robusto.

Comment: @ricidleiv, eu achei que sua pergunta foi bem formulada. Você deixou claro que qualquer solução (com qualquer linguagem) é útil para você.

Comment: Acredito que para melhorar a pergunta você deveria deixar ela mais "genérica", para que possa ser útil para uma quantidade maior de desenvolvedores. Por exemplo no título: "Como obter valores de uma coluna de várias tabelas apresentadas em uma página web?" Daí dentro da pergunta, você até pode ser um pouco mais específico. Deste modo, você abre o leque da sua pergunta e continua com seu problema resolvido.

Comment: A sugestão do @BrunoGasparotto é ótima! Assim todo mundo ganha

Comment: Obrigado @BrunoGasparotto, acatei sua sugestão do título e tentei reformular a introdução da pergunta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Abra o console do Chrome `(Ferramentas > Console Javascript)` e escreva o seguinte:

```js
$x("//tr[position() > 1]/td[2]/p/span/text()")
```

Isso vai chamar a função Javascript `$x` (definida para o console do Chrome) e retornar o resultado da expressão [XPath](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) fornecida como parâmetro.

### Explicação da expressão XPath

- `//tr[position() > 1]`: seleciona todos os elementos `tr` da página exceto o primeiro
- `td[2]`: seleciona apenas o segundo elemento `td` (i.e., a segunda coluna); você pode mudar o número da coluna ou usar `td[position()=1 or position()=2]` para selecionar as duas primeiras colunas, por exemplo.
- `p/span`: seleciona o elemento `span` dentro do elemento `p` (isso vale para a página do seu exemplo; para outras páginas, você deve verificar os elementos dentro do `td`)
- `text()` seleciona o conteúdo da tag.

### Uso em linguagens de programação

A solução mais prática em qualquer linguagem de programação envolve a XPath com alguma biblioteca de XML. Exemplo em Ruby:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'openssl'
OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(ARGV[0]).read)
doc.xpath("//tr[position() > 1]/td[2]/p/span/text()").each { |x| puts x}
```

Exemplo de uso

```sh
ruby script.rb 'https://www.iomat.mt.gov.br/do/navegadorhtml/mostrar.htm?id=630237&edi_id=3580'
```

Comment: Achei ótima a solução Rodrigo, porém se você pudesse explicar detalhadamente oque o comando faz (por exemplo, qual dos parâmetros representa a coluna a ser buscada) seria ótimo, tornaria mais "adaptável", pois é uma solução boa pra muita gente, mas nem todos conhecem a sintaxe proposta.